# Bypass PDO constructor fetch parameter error

Tags: php, pdo

```
class Event  extends DB_CONNECTION {

    private $EVNT_ID;
    private $Organizer;
    private $name;
    private $venue;
    private $discription;
    private $picture;
    private $Address;
    private $start_datetime;
    private $end_datetime;
    private $category;
    private $topic;
    private $Ticket;
    private $Sponsor;
    private $Special_guest;
    private $active;

    function __construct(Organizer $org )   {   
        $this->Organizer = $org;
        $this->Ticket = Ticket::get_tickets($this);
        $this->Sponsor = new Sponsor($this);
        parent::__construct();

    }
}


public function fetch_events() {

    $sql = "SELECT * ";
    $sql .= "FROM `event` ";
    $sql .= " ORDER BY `EVNT_ID` DESC LIMIT 21 ";

    $this->data_set = self::query( $sql );
    $this->data_set->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Event' );

    $events = $this->data_set->fetchAll();
    return (isset($events) ) ? $events : false;

}
```

This is my event class constructor

Currently developing event management system using PHP and PDO to for database connection.

I have chosen PDO for its fetch mode option, to initialize Objects in SQL query. but get a constructor error.

I can't use my constructor with argument because PDO issues `"cannot recreate __construct "` error when fetching data from that class.

Is there a way to bypass this? Or should I change the structure of my class and use `init()` function to initialize my object instead of using __constructor?

Comment: It's not clear what exact role PDO plays here, what overall design you have or what line of code triggers that error. Could you please edit the question and share valid code that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do not extend DB connection class. 
Create an instance and send it as a constructor parameter instead

Comment: can you tell me the reason, is  there side effect or something...sorry i'm newbie